# Spark submission on DCOS cluster fails with java.net.UnknownHostException: hdfs

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hdfs, mesos, dcos

I am running a `spark-submit` in cluster/rest mode on a DCOS cluster:

```
$ ./spark-submit  --deploy-mode cluster --master mesos://localhost:7077 --conf spark.master.rest.enabled=true --conf spark.mesos.uris=http://api.hdfs.marathon.l4lb.thisdcos.directory/v1/endpoints/hdfs-site.xml,http://api.hdfs.marathon.l4lb.thisdcos.directory/v1/endpoints/core-site.xml --conf spark.mesos.executor.docker.image=someregistry:5000/someimage:2.0.0-rc3 --conf spark.eventLog.enabled=true --conf spark.eventLog.dir=hdfs://hdfs/history --conf spark.executor.extraClassPath=/opr/spark/dist/elasticsearch-spark-20_2.11-6.4.2.jar  --conf spark.mesos.driverEnv.SPARK_HDFS_CONFIG_URL=http://api.hdfs.marathon.l4lb.thisdcos.directory/v1/endpoints/hdfs-site.xml --conf spark.executor.memory=42G --conf spark.driver.memory=8G --conf  spark.executor.cores=8 --driver-class-path /opt/spark/dist/elasticsearch-spark-20_2.11-6.4.2.jar http://hostname/somescript.py
```

The task fails as follows:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.UnknownHostException: hdfs
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.SecurityUtil.buildTokenService(SecurityUtil.java:374)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.NameNodeProxies.createNonHAProxy(NameNodeProxies.java:310)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.NameNodeProxies.createProxy(NameNodeProxies.java:176)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:668)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:604)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:148)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2598)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:91)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2632)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2614)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:370)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.getHadoopFileSystem(Utils.scala:1853)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.EventLoggingListener.<init>(EventLoggingListener.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:530)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:236)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: hdfs
    ... 26 more
```

I have created a tunnel from my localhost:7707 to master 7707 because the internal uri:7707 was directly reachable;

**edit**: I think it could be related to my executors not being able to read `core-site.xml` where the following declaration resides

```
<property>
    <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
    <value>hdfs://hdfs</value>
</property>
```

Do I need to point my local `spark` installation at these files somehow?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the `--conf spark.eventLog.dir=hdfs://hdfs/history`

You need to change it to `--conf spark.eventLog.dir=hdfs://HDFS_NAME_NODE_HOSTNAME:8020/hdfs/history`

Note: Replace HDFS_NAME_NODE_HOSTNAME with the actual Namenode hostname.